# how to get the variable name of a JLabel when its clicked

Tags: java, jlabel, mouselistener

For example I declared a new `JLabel` called `label1`,, I want when I click on that Label to print the name of it then to print `label1` and here is my code..

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("test");
label1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
           System.out.println(label1.getVariableName());
        }
    }
```

the expected result is : `lable1` 
is there any method of the `JLabel` to know the name of the variable of that `Label`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such simple way. Think about it: A single `JLabel` object could be referenced by many separate variable names:

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("test");
JLabel label2 = label1;
JLabel label3 = label2;
```

Or it could have no variable name *at all*:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("test"));
frame.getContentPane().getComponent(0).addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { ... });
```

Furthermore, not all variable names exist at run time. Field names do, but local variable names (within methods) do not; they exist only in the source code, and not in the compiled bytecode.

If your variable is a field on a class, then you can, as a hack, use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to iterate the fields of your object and find one that has the desired value:

```
try {
    for (java.lang.reflect.Field f : yourObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        if (f.get(yourObject) == label1) {
            System.out.println(f.getName());
        }
    }
} catch (Throwable t) {
    throw new RuntimeException(t);
}
```

(where `yourObject` is the instance of the class where the field is declared; e.g, the `JFrame`).

Using reflection for this is so ugly you should not use it for anything except debugging.

Otherwise, please explain more about what you're [actually](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) trying to do and there may be a workaround.

Comment: Okay man thanks for those info :) I'll try to put different text values and look for the text of the labels

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved using reflection, but that is not a nice thing to do. Another way to go around this is to maintain a `Map` of `<Unique ID of a label>` --> `<The variable name>`.

Of course, you will have to update the map each time you change the variable names, but it could be OK for you purposes.